# how to specify a page title in a django views.py file using a context variable?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to specify a page title that shows up in the browser tab within a views.py file for a class based view. I am working with a file that uses a base template html page for many different pages where I am trying specify the title using something such as:

```
{% block title %}{{ view.build_page_title }}{% endblock %}
```

in the views.py file I am trying something like this:

```
class ExampleReportView(BaseReportView):

    def build_page_title(self):
        return 'Example Page Title'
```

This does not seem to be working.  I am an absolute beginner in Django Python.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: How does `BaseReportView` look like?

Comment: At the top of the views.py file it starts with:

class BaseReportView(BaseSecureView):

and has a lot of definitions under that such as:
def build_report_title(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('need to implement build_report_title to return the name of the report')

Answer (score 4):

You don't pass values to the template by defining arbitrary methods on your view class; the template has no access to the view at all.

Instead, the view class will call its own `get_context_data` to determine the values to pass to the template; you can override that and add your own value.

```
class ExampleReportView(BaseReportView):

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super(ExampleReportView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        data['build_page_title'] = 'Example Page Title'
        return data
```

Of course, you can add as many values as you like inside that method.

Comment: Actually, the view instance has been part of the context [since 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.5/#new-view-variable-in-class-based-views-context) for exactly that reason. I'm not sure I like that pattern over overriding `get_context_data()`, but it's possible nonetheless.

Comment: Shows how often I use class-based views. Reminds me a bit of the Angular controller pattern.

Comment: Darn for some reason I still am not getting it to show up - I must be doing some thing wrong.  I tried using that get_context_data approach above and am using {% block title %}{{ view.build_page_title }}{% endblock %} in the html but no luck.  I may have someone on my team try to help when they can.  I will post any success I have.  Thanks

Comment: @user3408132: For `get_context_data`, you've use just use `build_page_title`, not `view.build_page_title`.

Comment: With my method you wouldn't access it via view, just `{{ build_page_title }}`. But as knbk points out, I was wrong about the template not having access to the view, so your original syntax should work.

Comment: Yes for some reason I still do not have it working:  I am using this:
{% block title %}{{ build_page_title }}{% endblock %} in the html 

and this in the views.py file

def build_page_title(self):
        return 'Example Page Title'

Comment: In my PyCharm editor it is saying that the build_page_title Method may be static

Comment: After help from one of my fellow devs I found that in the BaseReportView the title was being used in a return dict { title=self.build_report_title() } and it is now working when using the html like this {% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}  - thanks for your help you guys much appreciated.  I did not post the whole BaseReportView earlier since I did not know if that had any sensitive info work related info in it.  My coworker just mentioned that we solved it by putting it in the context.